# Custom List for specific product on woocomerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a delivery site in wordrpess and woocomerce. On the menu listing i need to hide prices on specific product IDs. Let's say because I don't want to discourage our clients entering specific products.

I tried with custom css through wordpress but I didn't manage to hide the price on **specific** product (ID4326).

```
 .post-4326 .products-list-view .prod_hold .price_hold  {
    display: none ;
}
```

Any ideas how to make it specific ?

Comment: Can you post the website along with a couple examples of products you want the price hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Check the ID of the product inside the loop, then you can use if statement to check the current product ID, like this:

```
<ul class="products">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                global $product;
                if($product->get_id() == /*Your ID*/){
                   //Display everything except price
                }
                else{
                   //Display all features
                }
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul><!–/.products–>
```